# Handle Multiple PHP Responses in Front-End (JavaScript or HTML5)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to handle multiple responses from PHP (multiple echoes generated from the loop in PHP) to Front-End (JavaScript to HTML5). The reason for that I have got progression bar in the HTML page so I want to update the progression bar according to responses receives from PHP.

I have tried using AJAX. I send AJAX request using JavaScript but it seems that an AJAX request can't be left open for multiple responses.

Without Ajax, I manage to print the PHP responses immediately to the webpage but I want to handle the responses using Javascript DOM.

**PHP code:**

```
   $proc = popen("$RDir $workingMainRFile $workingDirData $workingDirReport $fileName $workingRFiles " . escapeshellarg($title), 'r');
        //echo '<pre>';

        while (!feof($proc)) {
            $total += strlen(fread($proc, 4096));
            $part = strlen(fread($proc, 4096));
            $current += $part;
            $prec = intval((($current / 185256) * 100));
            if ($prec >= 100) {
                $prec = 100;

            $myObj->prec = $prec;
            echo json_encode($myObj);

            @ flush();
        }
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
function getPrec() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myBarText");
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.display = "block";
var form = document.getElementById('formUpload');
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {

                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                elem.style.width = myObj.prec;
            } else {

                console.log("Error", xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "php/upload.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

I would like to handle the multiple PHP responses using JavaScript DOM like the following:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myBarText");
elem.style.width = myObj.prec;
```

So that for each response I want to update the width of the progression bar.

Comment: You don’t have “multiple responses” here, not in terms of HTTP - you are just trying to flush the output buffer in a loop. That doesn’t change anything about the basic principle of _one_ HTTP request getting _one_ response in return. You could theoretically react to one of the “earlier” readyStates in your client-side code - but I doubt that will actually work in this case, because you are sending multiple independent JSON encoded data structures here, so what ever partial response you receive at any given point, will probably not go through `JSON.parse` to begin with.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would say my server generates the streaming response not “multiple responses”. I have also tried XMLHttpRequest progress but not fired for streaming response.  @misorude